# "numberedList" feature in CKEditor 5 in Reactjs doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I read many questions and their answers about CKEditor 5 but I've not resolved my problem yet.
Here my react component that I used for CKEditor:

```
import React from 'react';
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

ClassicEditor.defaultConfig = {
    toolbar: [
        "heading", "|", "bold", "fontFamily", "italic", "link", "bulletedList", "numberedList", "blockQuote", "insertTable", "undo", "redo"
],

    // This value must be kept in sync with the language defined in webpack.config.js.
     language: 'fa'
};

const BusinessDescription = ({
        onChange,
       defaultValue
}) => {
return <div className="Business-editor ">
    <CKEditor
        editor={ ClassicEditor }
        data={defaultValue || ''}
        onBlur={ ( event, editor ) => {
            onChange(editor.getData());
        }}
    />

</div>;
};
export default BusinessDescription;
```

My problem is:
When a user selects "numberedList" icon it doesn't work, also when selects "bulletedList" icon,
but when selects "blockQuote" then "bulletedList", the features for block quote and bulleted list  work well. The weierd situation will happened when a user selects "blockQuote" then "numberedList". in this situation the features for block quote and bulleted list work again and under no circumstances "numberedList" doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Add this css.

```
.ck.ck-content ul,
.ck.ck-content ul li {
  list-style-type: inherit;
}

.ck.ck-content ul {
  /* Default user agent stylesheet, you can change it to your needs. */
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.ck.ck-content ol,
.ck.ck-content ol li {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}
.ck.ck-content ol {
  /* Default user agent stylesheet, you can change it to your needs. */
  padding-left: 40px;
}
```

The styles must have been overrided.

[github-comment](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/1672#issuecomment-479470907)

Answer (score 1):

Hesam Make a CKEditorStyle.css file and add the Following Code to that file

**CKEditorStyle.css**

```
.ck.ck-content ul,
.ck.ck-content ul li {
  list-style-type: inherit;
}
.ck.ck-content ul {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.ck.ck-content ol,
.ck.ck-content ol li {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}
.ck.ck-content ol {
  padding-left: 40px;
}
.ck-editor__editable_inline {
  padding: 0 30px !important;
}
```

Then In your CKEditor-related file import, the CKEditorStyle.css file by

**CKEditor File**

```
import './CKEditorStyle.css' //I'm assuming you are making this file in the same directory.
 

**configurations**
    const config = {
    blockToolbar: {
      items: [ 'paragraph', 'heading1', 'heading2', '|', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList' ],
      shouldNotGroupWhenFull: true
    },
    ckfinder: {
      // Upload the images to the server using the CKFinder QuickUpload command.
      uploadUrl:
          // 'https://localhost:44374/api/v1/announcements/upload-file?command=QuickUpload&type=Images&responseType=json'
          'https://ckeditor.com/apps/ckfinder/3.4.5/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files&responseType=json'
    },
    mediaEmbed: {
        previewsInData: true
    },

    table: {
        contentToolbar: ['tableColumn', 'tableRow', 'mergeTableCells']
    }
  };


<CKEditor
          data={form.values[fieldName]}
          editor={ClassicEditor}
          config={config}
          onChange={DescriptionChangeHandler}
          className="sarampeema"
        //   onReady={editor => {
        //     editor.editing.view.change(writer => {
        //         writer.setStyle('height', '100px', editor.editing.view.document.getRoot());
        //         writer.setStyle(
        //             'z-index',
        //             '999999 !important',
        //             editor.editing.view.document.getRoot()
        //         );
        //     });
        // }}
        />
```